# Como distribuir iOS apps fora da AppStore

Tags: ios, app, iphone, appstore

Gostaria de saber como funciona o processo de distribuição de iOS apps fora da AppStore. Gostaria de realizar o processo como o "AppNana", no qual ao você entrar no site deles (www.appnana.com) através de um iDevice, é solicitada a instalação do aplicativo.
*OBS: Não se trata de um atalho na área de trabalho apenas, pois o app é realmente instalado e carregado no iDevice.

O objetivo é fornecer o .ipa do meu app a todos que quiserem baixar, assim como o AppNana.
Qual é o esquema e quanto custa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa do [**iOS Developer Enterprise Program**](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) (*200 dólares a mais do que o programa normal que custa 99 dólares, ou seja 299 dólares*), que além de outras vantagens, vai permitir que você distribua aplicativos proprietário hospedados em seu próprio servidor.

Acredito que a ideia deste programa é para uso interno das empresas, mas acabou sendo utilizado para outros propósitos como no exemplo que você citou, que ainda assim, acho que não fere a política da *Apple*.

[Nesta página](http://support.apple.com/en-is/HT6584) de suporte da *Apple* você pode ver o processo que acontece ao instalar este tipo de aplicativo, e que eles recomendam para os usuários que seja instalado somente se o servidor for seguro e operado pela própria empresa.

Comment: Tem um limite de pessoas ou iDevices que podem baixar o app?

Comment: Neste programa não há limitações para distribuição.

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de distribuir meu .ipa sem custos ? Ou sem uma conta de desenvolver ?

Comment: De forma legal, seguindo a política da Apple, infelizmente não.